# Test MongoDB repository method

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mockito

I want to test a mongo-db repository method, `Page<TestLog> findAll(Pageable pageable);`,

that takes as parameter a `Pageable(int pageNumber, int size)`,

and returns `pageNumber` page with less or equal to `size` entries.

When I use the test below, I just get all the entries, when I would expect to get only 1.
I am trying to find out the appropriate way to achieve this/test the repo method.

```
public class TestLogRequestTest {

@Mock private TestLogRepository testLogRepository;
@Rule public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@InjectMocks public TestServiceImpl testService;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}


@Test
public void testRepoMethods() {

    List<TestLog> testLogs = new ArrayList<>();

    TestLog testLog = new TestLog();

    testLog.setMessage("message");
    testLog.setStatus(404);
    testLogs.add(testLog);
    testLog.setMessage("MESSAGE-2");
    testLogs.add(auditLog);

    testLog.setStatus(200);
    testLogs.add(auditLog);
    testLog.setMessage("200-message-1");
    testLogs.add(auditLog);

    Page<TestLog> page = new PageImpl<>(auditLogs);
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1);

    when(testLogRepository.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(page);
    Page<TestLog> testLogsPage = testLogRepository.getAllBy(pageable);
    ...
```

Comment: TestLogRepository `getAllBy` code?

Comment: public interface TestLogRepository extends MongoRepository<TestLog, String> {

    Page<TestLog> getAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}

Comment: There is no convention in spring-data for your method name `getAllBy(Pageable pageable)`, there is a provided method from spring-data repository called `findAll(Pageable pageable)` and it will return page of requested number of elements

Comment: EX: `testLogRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 1));`

Comment: Thank you! In test this returns null though.

Comment: Because you are not mocking the function `findAll` But still this is not valid scenario, because this is not real testing, and you mock the whole repository functions.

Comment: You have to check page number, number of elements. But you don't need to mock the repository because there is an embedded mongo implementation provided from spring itself, Just you have to add some dependency. [reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add a more concrete example?